# Extracting the value of an input field from jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery form plugin to do some Ajax processing, it works fine but now I have got stuck.
I have a block of code where I need to extract a value (app) so I can pass it into another function.

```
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

         $(".updateUserRole").ajaxForm(function () {
            app = $(".updateUserRole").find('input').fieldValue()[1];
            alert(JSON.stringify(app));

        });
    });
```

This block works ok; I get the value of the field in the app variable but there are several occurrences of the updateUserRole form  on the page and this code always returns the value of the first one.

What I really want is something like this;

```
     $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

         $(".updateUserRole").ajaxForm(function () {
            app = $(this).find('input').fieldValue()[1];
            alert(JSON.stringify(app));

        });
    });
```

Which I think should just return the value for the current occurrence; but it doesn't, the value is undefined.

I am obviously misunderstanding how jQuery works here, can some helpful person please help me out?

Comment: why is this wrapped in ajaxComplete? What is `fieldValue()` method? You need a more absolute selector for the input if it isn't the first input in the form.

Comment: It is wrapped in ajaxComplete because the list of applications is loaded by an ajax call, using the ajaxForm function from the jQuery Form Plugin.

The [fieldValue](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#fields) method also comes from the form plugin.

Comment: There are a number of updateUserRole forms on the page, what I am trying to do is attach a behaviour so that when the user clicks on one of them I can capture the "app" value for that particular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd better answer my own question for completeness, my working version is;

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

     $(".updateUserRole").ajaxForm(function () {
        app = getQueryVariable(this.data, 'applicationId');
        alert(JSON.stringify(app));

    });
});
```

this.data contains the information I need but returns a query string so I have used a slightly modified version of getQueryVariable from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/%22CSS%20Tricks%22) to extract the variable "applicationId" that I required.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this and that it is possible to do it completely in jQuery but this works and that is what I need.  If anyone can offer a better version I would be happy to see it.